# eclipse hot-keys

Tags: eclipse

Подскажите пожалуйста какой хот-кей соответствует ПКМ в Eclipse, что то похожее это shift+alt+f но это просто открытие вкладки file, а при нажатии ПКМ меню немного не такое выскакивает но как это сделасть с клавы не могу найти.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно посмотреть в настройках, Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys. У меня, похоже (Oxygen 4.7, Linux) вообще изначально ничего не назначено, так что можно настроить на любую свободную комбинацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо решило проблему!!!!